# [Vue warn]: Property "$store" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Im newbie and making project of online-shop.
And i got two errors which I can't fix in any way:

1)[Vue warn]: Property "$store" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

2)Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from "axios";

 const store = createStore({
    state:{
        products:[]
    },
    mutations:{
        SET_PRODUCTS_TO_STATE:(state,products)=>{
            state.products = products;
        }
    },
    actions:{
        GET_PRODUCTS_FROM_API({commit}) {
            return axios('http://localhost:3000/products',{
                method:"GET"
            })
                .then((products) =>{
                commit('SET_PRODUCTS_TO_STATE',products.data);
                return products;
            })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error)
                    return error;
                })
        }
    },
    getters:{
        PRODUCTS(state){
            return state.products;
        }
    }

});
export default store;
```

v-cataloge.vue

```
<template>
  <div class = 'v-catalog'>
  <h1>Catalog</h1>
<div class ="v-catalog__list">
  <v-catalog-item
  v-for="product in this.$store.state.products"
  :key="product.article"
  v-bind:product_data="product"
  @sendArticle="showChildArticleInConsole"
  />
</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

repository:https://github.com/BIGBASEDFLOPPA/Project1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue3.x,  you should import store in someItem.vue
in your case, following code:

```
import { useStore } from 'vuex';
export default {
  setup(){
    let store = useStore()
    let products = store.state.products

    return {
      products
    }
  }
}

// use products in template
v-for="product in products"
```

Comment: How to use that with options API?

Answer (score 2):

If you take the "this" out it will work

```
v-for="product in $store.state.products"
```

You need to use "this" in the script, but not in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `mapState` [helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) to write cleaner code.

First import it:

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";
```

Add it inside `computed` with the spread operator to [simplify the syntax](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#object-spread-operator):

```
computed: {
   ...mapState(['products']),
},
```

Now you can use `products` without `$store.state`:

```
<v-catalog-item v-for="product in products" ...
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to create a store.js in Vue 3. In the file v-catalog.vue you have to write the following code

```
 <template>
  <div class = 'v-catalog'>
  <h1>Catalog</h1>
<div class ="v-catalog__list">
  <v-catalog-item
  v-for="product in products"
  :key="product.article"
  v-bind:product_data="product"
  @sendArticle="showChildArticleInConsole"
  />
</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import vCatalogItem from './v-catalog-item'
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  components: {
    vCatalogItem
  },
  name: "v-catalog",
  data() {
    return {
      products: []
    }
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/products`);

      this.products = res.data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, you're doing a bad practice

Comment: Ok. Sorry.  I found another solution to this problem.

Comment: Please don't post many answers, just edit one with relevant answer to the question

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32570485)